# Can you change the base font-family in Tailwind config?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I’ve added new font families in my `tailwind.config.js` file. These are available with the `.font-sans` class, but I would like to change the global font-family as well. The `'tailwindcss/base'` import adds a generic sans-serif family on the `html, body {}` selector.

Is there a way to change this global font family in the config file, rather than just adding in a new style to undo it?

I’d like to keep the overall CSS to a minimum and not have to add extra CSS to undo styles I don’t need. I couldn’t see any option in the docs that would apply to this.

Comment: I was thinking the same and started a discussion at https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7496. I think the solution will be to add to the documentation. All answers here that says to change `theme.fontFamily.sans` are correct. Doesn't really matter how you do it as long as `theme.fontFamily.sans` is changed because that variable is used [on line 32 of preflight.css](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/75ba4e0f8f97e2f4475cf863d945801bd04b1df8/src/css/preflight.css#L32).

Comment: This is now documented at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#customizing-the-default-font

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For me it worked to override 'sans', because that's whats being used by default.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['"PT Sans"', 'sans-serif']
    }
  },
}
```

(Note that theme.fontFamily is overriding the 3 defaults, so if you copy paste the above code you lose font-serif and font-mono)

But it would be weird to override 'sans' with something like a serif stack, so in those cases you can define the stack and apply it to the html/body tag:

```
<body class="font-serif"> <!-- Or whatever your named your font stack -->
```

[More about tailwind font families](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family/)

Answer (score 13):

I use Inter font and this is what working for me after hours of trying a lot of suggestions and tutorials:

```
module.exports = {
  important: true,
  future: {
    removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
    purgeLayersByDefault: true,
  },
  purge: [
    './components/**/*.js',
    './pages/**/*.js'],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: '640px',
      md: '768px',
      lg: '1024px',
      xl: '1280px',
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: [
          '"Inter"',
          'system-ui',
          '-apple-system',
          'BlinkMacSystemFont',
          '"Segoe UI"',
          'Roboto',
          '"Helvetica Neue"',
          'Arial',
          '"Noto Sans"',
          'sans-serif',
          '"Apple Color Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
          '"Noto Color Emoji"',
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [
    require( 'tailwindcss' ),
    require( 'precss' ),
    require( 'autoprefixer' ),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 12):

When you [install](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) Tailwind CSS following the official guide, the default font-family that applies to the HTML element of your project corresponds to the `font-sans` utility class, as below (Preflight);

```css
font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
```

In order to modify the Tailwind [Preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#extending-preflight) configuration, you can make use of `@layer` to extend the *base* as below;

```css
/*
 * Override default font-family above
 * with CSS properties for the .font-serif utility.
 */
@tailwind base;
@layer base {
  html {
    @apply font-serif;
  }
}
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Though global (as it applies to the root HTML element of the document), the approach described above overrides the font-family defined in Tailwind Preflight configuration but ensure it remains in your compiled CSS, when used.

Assuming you want to use "Segoe UI" with Roboto and sans-serif only as *sans* font-family applied to your HTML element in the same order, without override, make use of the snippet below;

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const { fontFamily } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: [
        '"Segoe UI"',
        'Roboto',
        'sans-serif',
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

In case you want your new newly defined *sans* `font-family` to be applied (still without override) but with Tailwind's as default fallback, modify your script as below;

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const { fontFamily } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: [
        '"Segoe UI"',
        'Roboto',
        'sans-serif',
        ...fontFamily.sans,
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Please note: in the last scenario above, the font-family applied to the HTML element of your project could contain duplicate font listings, if already exiting in the CSS properties of Tailwind's `.font-sans` utility class (that is the case for the three fonts used in the example above).

Let's say you want to use [IBM Plex Sans Variable](https://github.com/IBM/plex/tree/master/IBM-Plex-Sans-Variable) as your custom *sans* font, with the regular Tailwind CSS `.font-family` *sans*, without override, make use of the snippet below, then import the font into your project;

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const { fontFamily } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: [
        '"IBM Plex Sans"',
        ...fontFamily.sans,
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Remember: use the same font-family name as in your tailwind.config.js file as name for your custom font - here: `"IBM Plex Sans"`.

Comment: Good point with approach leveraging the Preflight.

Comment: I had to re-read your answer a few times to get that the **only** way to override preflight `font-family` is to define your own font family as `sans` in _tailwind.config.js_. I tried the `@layer base` but somehow missed that it keeps the default Tailwind CSS `font-family` in the CSS. "the approach described above overrides the font-family defined in Tailwind Preflight configuration but ensure it remains in your compiled CSS, when used." <- is not super clear about that.

Comment: Thanks @dotnetCarpenter. Please feel free to edit and enhance clarity.

Answer (score 8):

This is the proper way to add a custom font with good fallbacks (in case the browser couldn't download the font, the site should still look pretty with the default font).

1. Put font file in your project folder.
2. Add font to `Head` section so that it loads in all pages:

```html
<link
            rel="preload"
            href="/fonts/inter-var-latin.woff2"
            as="font"
            type="font/woff2"
            crossOrigin="anonymous"
          />
```

3. Mention font in tailwind global css file so that it applies to all pages:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Inter";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100 900;
    font-display: optional;
    src: url(/fonts/inter-var-latin.woff2) format("woff2");
  }
}
```

4. Tell tailwind to prioritize this font. in `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
/* disable eslint errors if any */
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Inter", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

5. Vibe.

To verify that the custom font is loaded properly use [WhatFont](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm) chrome ext or go to dev tools, inspect a text, and scroll to HTML CSS:

[image]

---

PS: You can see Tailwind custom font implementation on my (Next.js) site: https://github.com/GorvGoyl/Personal-Site-Gourav.io

Comment: I have checked your code. U have used next/font and also added preload link in _document.js and also overridden in tailwind CSS. It loads the same font files twice with different paths. 

I am using Next.js v12.1.0 so I cannot use font/next. I am still getting confused because I am already adding font files through font as shown in step 3. I just wanted to add the pre-connect tag to it. therefore adding a link in _document.js even though I have (eot,SVG,ttf,woff,woff2) files for multiple fonts. On the browser, it downloads all which are even not necessary.
Could you guide me in proper way ?

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me when I wanted my app to use *Roboto* font as a default sans font:

In `tailwind.config.js`:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

const fontFamily = defaultTheme.fontFamily;
fontFamily['sans'] = [
  'Roboto', // <-- Roboto is a default sans font now
  'system-ui',
  // <-- you may provide more font fallbacks here
];

module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: fontFamily, // <-- this is where the override is happening
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

This override variant modifies only `font-sans` family and preserves `font-serif` and `font-mono` families.

Comment: Somehow only this worked. When I tried modifying sans inline at theme.fontFamily or theme.extend.fontFamiliy, none worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a custom downloaded font, so I did it this way: Download a free font (eg BeautifulQueen.otf)  and put it into your public/font folder. Go to your globals.css file where you have your tailwindcss css stuff (@tailwind base;@tailwind components;@tailwind utilities;) add this after it file /styles/globals.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@layer base {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'BeautifulQueen';
    src: url('/font/BeautifulQueen.otf');
  }
}
// rest of your css goes below
```

Now go to your tailwind.config.js file in your root folder file /tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['BeautifulQueen', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

You only need the fontFamily and sans line. Sans is tailwind's default font name, you are overriding the first font to your custom font.

How it works: Tailwind config file sans: 'BeautifulQueen' links to your css @font-face name font-family: 'BeautifulQueen' and it uses your src source of your font file location. src: url('/font/BeautifulQueen.otf');

Note: in your globals.css file, remove any font-family that is being used (eg in Nextjs it auto create

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}
```

You need to comment out or remove that font-family being referenced, eg below. If you dont remove it, you'll be using it and not your custom font.

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the key was to add

```
, ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans]
```

in the

```
fontFamily: {
   sans: ["Inter", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
},
```

to override the default font-family